# Prove if (a,p)=1, then {a,2a,3a,…,pa} is a complete residue system modulo p.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm having a hard time proving this, and I'm not sure where to start. Help appreciated

Comment: Hint: Show that if $1\le k\lt l\le p$, then $ka\not\equiv la\pmod{p}$, meaning that $p$ does not divide $la-ka$.

Comment: Please search before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Show that if $am\equiv an\pmod{p}$ then $m\equiv n\pmod{p}$.